# Public versus private inheritance when some of the parent's methods need to be exposed?

Tags: inheritance, c++11, encapsulation

Public inheritance means that all fields from the base class retain their declared visibility, while private means that they are forced to 'private' within the derived class's scope.

*What should be done if some of the parent's members (say, methods) need to be publicly exposed?*

I can think of two solution. Public inheritance somewhat breaks encapsulation. Furthermore, when you need to find out where is the method foo() defined, one needs to look at a chain of base classes.

Private inheritance solves these problems, but introduces burden to write wrappers (more text). Which might be a good thing in the line of verbosity, but makes changes of interfaces incredibly cumbersome.

What considerations am I missing? What constraints on the type of project are important? How to choose between the two (I am not even mentioning 'protected')?

Note that I am targeting non-virtual methods. There isn't such a discussion for virtual methods (or is there).

Comment: If you only need to expose a few of the parent's methods, why are you using inheritance?

Comment: @Doval, do you mean that I should be using composition?

Comment: That's the impression I get from the question. Additionally, isn't this C++ specific? Or are there other languages with the concept of "private inheritance"?

Comment: Composition should normally be preferred over inheritance. There are however times when it makes more sense to use private inheritance. See this question on stackoverflow.com: [When to use C++ private inheritance over composition?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6297331/774499)

Comment: In a way, private inheritance is sytactic sugar for composition...

Comment: If this is specific to C++, perhaps this should be tagged as such in addition to the current tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expose items that would otherwise have some kind of restricted access (i.e., private or protected) without writing a wrapper function by using the [`using` directive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
class base {
public:
    base();
    virtual ~base();
    void do_something();
    void do_something_else();
private:
    // elided
};

class derived : private base {
public:
    derived();
    virtual ~derived();
    using base::do_something();
};
```

In the above, the derived class exposes `base::do_something()` as a public method, but not `base::do_something_else()`.